# Configure WWW for Azure Shared Instance Site

Tags: asp.net, azure, dns

I'm hosting my first site on Azure. After much [trial and error](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/#bkmk_configurearecord), I got mysite.com to come up, but not if it's pre-fixed with www (getting a 404).

Here are my DNS settings:

**A Records:**

@    1.2.3.4

ftp  1.2.3.4

www  1.2.3.4

**CNAME**

awverify    awverify.mysite.azurewebsites.net

When I ping 1.2.3.4, the requests time out. How can I get www.mysite.com to resolve?

Comment: Apparently the ping may be blocked by Azure firewall and is a side issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I have set-up some of my Azure websites (and it works perfectly fine)

Assuming an Azure Website name is *myazurewebsite* and custom DNS is *mywebsite.com* I have 
one **A** record

1. Host name:`mywebsite.com` IP:`1.2.3.4` (IP taken from *domain management* in Azure Website)

And two **CNAME** records:

1. Alias:`awverify.mywebsite.com` points to host:`awverify.myazurewebsite.azurewebsites.net`
2. Alias:`www.mywebsite.com` points to host:`myazurewebsite.azurewebsites.net`

Then I have Azure Website configured with two domain names (*Configure > Domain Names*)

- mywebsite.com
- www.mywebsite.com

You may be missing `www` configuration in your DNS and Azure. I hope that will help.